# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.select.Select

Tags: java, apache, wicket-6

I'm facing this problem in the apache wicket framework.

```
WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.joy.ui.Registration()Root cause:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.select.Select
```

I have imported the jar file for `org.apahe.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.select.Select` in my project but the error is still showing...

```
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.select.Select;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.select.SelectOption;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you miss the `wicket-extensions.jar`. Download and add it to your classpath.